# Firestore user id is different of the document id react native firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I'm doing a simple user creation, but the id field in the firestore is null and the ids are different.

why is this happening? how to solve?

code below:

```
const auth = await authFB().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);

const db = firestore();

await db
        .collection('Clients')
        .doc(auth.user.uid)
        .set({
          id: auth.user.uid,
          name: {
            first: firstName,
            last: lastName
            }
         });
```

Document image below: (Look at id: null):

[image]

Comment: Is it user created in Auth database? Maybe authFB().createUserWithEmailAndPassword throw the error. Try to catch it and check

Comment: @SergeiSevriugin I am using like this: import authFB from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

Comment: @SergeiSevriugin its not returning error just register the user normally

Comment: I don't understand, in you code you set id and name properties for document with document qual to auth.user.uid? So when you created this document if you just got this id from createUserWithEmailAndPassword? and if you correctly set name name property using auth.user.uid, whey the id is not set ?

Comment: @SergeiSevriugin yes, this is my problem, the id is null and if i make a console.log (user.uid) the uid is not the same as the document id in the firestore

Comment: Well, because in your screen shot you have Client document with other properties like address for example but in the code you just set name and id. So, the record was created  before BUT in your code you just create new user and immediately set name and id for this user, so it should be other record in database with this id (uid)

Comment: No, its the same, I just delete from code so it wouldn't get too big @SergeiSevriugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create `const uid = auth.user.uid` and use this constant in two paces inside firestore update. For example:

```
const auth = await authFB().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);

const uid = auth.user.uid;      // <----

const db = firestore();

await db
        .collection('Clients')
        .doc(uid)              // <----
        .set({
          id: uid,             // <----
          name: {
            first: firstName,
            last: lastName
            }
         });
```